# Batch Insert SQL query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mysql-error-1064

I just keep getting the error 1064. I searched how to do while loops then declare local variables etc. and I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I tried to do it without the ";" and I tired setting the delimiter as "|" to be able to use ";" as a separator between lines (I read something somwhere that kind of said it could be the way to do it?..)

I'm trying to do that query on PhpMyAdmin and my MySql version is 5.1.36

I'm not going to explain what I'm trying as I believe it is easy to understand by simply reading my query below.

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v2 VARCHAR(10); 
WHILE v1 < 20 DO
SET v2 = CONCAT('Test ', CAST(v1 AS CHAR(2)));
INSERT INTO news(title,date, message) VALUES(v2, NOW(), v2);
SET v1 = v1 + 1;
END WHILE; 
END;
```

Comment: Is what you posted exactly what you are attempting to use?  Because there are lots of typos...  The content of the 1064 error message would help.

Comment: Are you running the above statements inside a routine? or as stand-alone statements.

Comment: as stand-alone statements. I'm not trying to create a procedure or a function. I was trying to add fake information in my database to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql only allows compound statements using the `BEGIN...END` tag inside stored programs.

From the [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/begin-end.html):

> BEGIN ... END syntax is used for
>   writing compound statements, which can
>   appear within stored programs

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i can see is a small syntax error within the CAST parameters.

You have:
    CAST(v1 ASCHAR(2))

You need:
    CAST(v1 AS CHAR(2))

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
DECLAREv2 VARCHAR(10);
```

to

```
DECLARE v2 VARCHAR(10);
```

Comment: I corrected this in the question, but asked for clarification if that really is the issue or a simple case of typos...

Comment: That was only a typo in my question.. It tried it again and still not working. the error Im getting is : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0; DECLARE v2 VARCHAR(10); WHILE v1 < 20 DO ' at line 2